# How do I programmatically generate a 404?

Tags: redirect, 404-error

How can I get something like this to work?

```
// in a plugin / theme:
// This imaginary function will make WordPress think that the 
// current request is a 404. 
// Ideally this function could be ran anywhere, but realistically it
// will probably have to be before the template_redirect hook runs.
generate_404_somehow();

// later...
add_action('template_redirect', function() {
    // should be "true"
    var_dump(is_404());
});
```

Basically under certain conditions, I want to tell WordPress to show its 404 template (which I can hook into later if I want) instead of the template it's about to load (eg a page or archive).

I know I could just do a `302` redirect to a non-existent page but that's very messy. I could also send a `404` HTTP header manually, but then I can't use WP's nice 404 page (I already have things that hook into `is_404()` that need to get fired at the right time).

Comment: Perhaps I could modify the query to search for a non-existent page.

Comment: Can you clarify the question here? Are you trying to run code on your theme's 404 page or do you intentionally want to create a 404 error?

Comment: I want to create a 404. I'll edit the question a bit...

Comment: in which case/when and why do you want to generate a 404 page?

Comment: I've needed to do this on at least 2 different occasions. Most recently was making legacy author pages give a `404`. It's also something that I'm sure I'll need again in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function generate_404_somehow() {
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query->is_404 = true;
}
add_action('wp','generate_404_somehow');
```

Of course, that will send all of you page to the 404 template. I don't know what the conditions are that this should fire or not fire.

Or to be more cautious (see comments) ...

```
function generate_404_somehow() {
   global $wp_query;
   $wp_query->set_404();
}
add_action('wp','generate_404_somehow');
```

Comment: This works but `$wp_query->set_404()` also runs `$wp_query->init_query_flags()`, which sets all the other `is_*` flags to false.

Comment: True, but I don't see the need for the (very minor) overhead. I would be interested to know if there is a case where this doesn't work. I can't find one.

Comment: I need to make sure that things like `is_single()` and `is_archive()` return false, so any hooks that check them are correct and don't add extra stuff to the 404 page (like the "Next" and "Previous" links). This depends on plugins and themes though.

Comment: I understand the caution. Using `$wp_query->set_404()` inside my function should cover it. I assume that that is what you decided to do.

Answer (score 1):

The other by s_ha_dum answers doesn't set the HTTP Header Status to *404 Not Found*. To do this adds `status_header( 404 )` to the function.

```
function generate_404_somehow() {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
}
add_action('wp','generate_404_somehow');
```

- [WordPress Code Reference: `status_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/status_header/)
- [MDN web doc: 404 not found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404)

Comment: You could additionally add `nocache_headers()` as seen in [`WP::handle_404()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/handle_404/).

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set_404();
$wp_query->max_num_pages = 0; // stop theme from showing Next/Prev links
```

This seems to set the HTTP headers and load the right template (with `is_404()` being true).