# How to force a 404 on WordPress

Tags: redirect, 404-error

I need to force a 404 on some posts based on conditions. I managed to do it ( although I don't know if I did it the right way) and I'm a getting my `404.php` template to load as expected.

**My code:**

```
function rr_404_my_event() {
  global $post;
  if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
    include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
    exit; # so that the normal page isn't loaded after the 404 page
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rr_404_my_event', 1 );
```

Code 2 from [this related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73738/how-do-i-programmatically-generate-a-404) - same problem:

```
function rr_404_my_event() {
  global $post;
  if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
  }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'rr_404_my_event' );
```

**My Issue:**

Although it *looks* good, I get a status `200 OK` if I check the network tab. Since it's a status `200`, I am afraid that search engines might index those pages too.

**Expected Behaviour:**

I want a status `404 Not Found` to be sent.

Comment: From the _related questions:_ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73738/how-do-i-programmatically-generate-a-404 – did you read that?

Comment: Yes, I still get a status `200` with that.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could try the Wordpress function `status_header()` to add the `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` header;

So your *Code 2* example would be:

```
function rr_404_my_event() {
  global $post;
  if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'rr_404_my_event' );
```

This function is for example used in this part:

```
function handle_404() {
    ...cut...
    // Guess it's time to 404.
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
    ...cut...
}
```

from the `wp` class in `/wp-includes/class-wp.php`.

So try using this modified *Code 2* example in addition to your `template_include` code.

Comment: The `Code 2` snippet you posted works perfectly. The `set_header()` was what was missing.

Comment: @birgire you refer to `set_header()` to add `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` but have used `status_header()` in your code?

Comment: @henrywright it looks like a typo there, I updated the answer, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 23):

This code worked for me:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'force_404' );
function force_404() {
    global $wp_query; //$posts (if required)
    if(is_page()){ // your condition
        status_header( 404 );
        nocache_headers();
        include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Handy. I'm checking for custom query parameters so I'm not using the action, but it makes for a very useful method in my plugin class.

Comment: Add the following to fix the page title:
`global $wp_query;`
`$wp_query->is_404 = true;`

Answer (score 4):

The most robust way I've found of achieving this is to do it in the `template_include` filter, like so:

```php
function wpse91900_force_404(string $template): string {
    if ($some_condition) {
        global $wp_query;

        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        nocache_headers();

        $template = get_404_template();
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter("template_include", "wpse91900_force_404");
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend forcing a 404.

If you're worried about search engines why not just do a "no-index,no-follow" meta on those pages and block it with robots.txt?

This may be a better way to block the content from being viewed

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'nifty_block_content', 99 );

function nifty_block_content( $template ) {
  if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( array( 'nifty-block-content.php' ) );
     }
    return $template;
}
```

You could probably also use this method to load `404.php` but I feel that using a page template might be a better option.

[source](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2012/10/16/how-i-run-a-membership-site)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I'll switch to using `locate_template()` instead. I think that `robots.txt.` isn't a guaranteed way to protect from indexation. Some search engines might still pick up the page. I do want the page to look like a normal 404 page. Also the posts are going to be dynamically added, editing the `robots.txt` file will add more trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share the way I used the marked solution

```
function fail_safe_for_authors() {
    if ((is_user_logged_in()) && (is_author()) && ($_COOKIE["user_role"] !== "administrator")) {
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
        }
}
add_action("wp", "fail_safe_for_authors");
```

I did this to separate **all user types** from the **administrator**, in this project, Only the admin can see the `author.php` page.

I hope it could help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'my_404' );
function my_404() 
{
    if ( is_404() ) 
    {
        header("Status: 404 Not Found");
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        nocache_headers();
        //var_dump(getallheaders()); var_dump(headers_list()); die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Redirecting on errors is terrible for your page ranking. Just show a template at the same location as the bad request. What will happen when you do that is you initially set a 404, and then the redirect alters it to a 301 or 302, which then redirects to a page that returns a 200. That then gets indexed by search engines as a valid page, which is explicitly what OP said he didn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Status codes are sent in the headers of HTTP requests. Your current function is hooked into a hook that will be called too late.

You should try to hook your function `rr_404_my_event()` into action `send_headers`.

I'm not sure if at that point in time it's even possible to check the Post ID, but give this a go:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'rr_404_my_event' );
function rr_404_my_event() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular( 'event' ) && !rr_event_should_be_available( $post->ID ) ) {
        include( get_query_template( '404' ) );
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        exit; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected some syntax errors from your codes. I don't even get my 404 template to load with that.

Comment: Perhaps, in your `404.php` you could load a different `header.php`, e.g. `<?php get_header('404'); ?>` to load `header-404.php`. In that header, you'd add `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');` in the `<head>` section.

Comment: @MarcDingena I guess you have to put the `header()` line above the one, when you output the template contents, otherwise you will get the correct template page shown, but the real HTTP status code will still be `200`.