# Using a custom post type for an RSS feed only

Tags: custom-post-types, rss

I've had a request from a client which is causing me a bit of a headache! They want an RSS feed which shows content that isn't featured anywhere on the website.

I've registered a new custom post type (stripped down code);

```
$alert_args = array( 
    'public' => false, 
    'show_ui' => true,
    'label' => 'Alerts', 
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
);
register_post_type( 'alerts', $alert_args );
```

For the RSS feed to work, it appears I need the `public` argument set to `TRUE` but I don't want these posts to be indexed by Google or to be used by website visitors. Any idea how I can get the RSS feed to work on it's own?

Thanks, Dan.

---EDIT---

Please note, in the end I had the change `get_post_type()` to `get_query_var( 'post_type' )` because the former doesn't work with archive template pages. See code;

```
if( 'alerts' === get_query_var( 'post_type' ) && ! is_feed() )
{
    $GLOBALS[ 'wp_query' ]->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    nocache_headers();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try forcing a `404`  using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92176/26350) method:

```
/**
 * Force 404 on all "alerts" custom post type pages except for the feed
 *
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162303/26350
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if( 'alerts' === get_post_type() && ! is_feed() )
    {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
        nocache_headers();
    }   
} );
```

with the following setup:

```
$alert_args = array( 
    'public'              => true, 
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'has_archive'         => true, 
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'label'               => 'Alerts', 
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
);

register_post_type( 'alerts', $alert_args );
```

to allow only access to the *feed* for the the `alerts` custom post type.

You might also want to consider adding an extra `! is_user_logged_in()` check, if you want to allow *logged in* users view the alerts or `! current_user_can( 'some_capability' )` for some user *capability* requirement.

Comment: This appears to work very well, thank you very much for the fast and effective answer. I never knew about the status_header() and nocache_headers() functions, so I'm pleased I asked the question.

Comment: see my minor change to code. Does that look ok to you?

Comment: @Dan I tested it on the default 2012 theme for the `post`  post type and that seems to block all archive pages as well. If you're using some attached taxonomy to the alerts, your method might not work there or with the `post` post type. Can you share the url structure where this didn't work for you?

Comment: I wanted the post type archive blocking too, which is why I changed that code. domain.com/alerts/ would have been the URL in question, just the post type's archive.

Comment: @Dan strange, `example.com/alerts/` is blocked on my 2012 theme install using the `get_post_type()` version. Then there's always the possibility of using specific template tags like: `is_post_type_archive( 'alerts' )`.

Comment: So if /alerts/ is a custom post type archive, what do you get when you var_dump() the get_post_type() function?

Comment: I get `string 'alerts' (length=6)`, that comes from the `get_post()` fallback of `get_post_type()`, that uses the  `$GLOBALS['post']`.