# Custom WP_Query always respond with 200 status even when no entry

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pagination, 404-error, paged

I'm using a custom `WP_Query`. The code is something like below:

```
$portfolio_args = array(
    'post_type'           => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'      => 5,
    'paged'               => get_query_var( 'page' )
);

$portfolio_query = new WP_Query($portfolio_args);
```

Now, my portfolio post type has 15 entries (thus it is good for 3 pages). I can navigate to all these pages, but the issue is even the pages which does not have any portfolio entry (e.g. `/page/4/, /page/5, ...`) loads just fine (i.e. throws 200 in response header), whereas, I'm expecting it to throw a 404 error if the page has not any entry.

Is it the expected behaviour for custom query pagination? If so do I need to force a 404 response header somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Response is based on the results of the *main query*. The decision is made before the template is loaded, which is how WP is able to serve a 404 template in the case of a 404.

As you've learned, the `page` post type lets you paginate endlessly in both the format `pagename/page/n/`, as well as the singular pattern `pagename/n/`. To generate a 404 for a different query, you'd need to hook something like [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) to check if your custom query contains posts so you can force a 404 before output starts.

The preferred solution is to set the `has_archive` argument for your custom post type, which enables an archive page. The main query will then be your collection of portfolio posts, and pagination will work as expected.

Comment: So, will I have access to '$portfolio_query' object in 'template_redirect' hook? Any example of using this hook for forcing a 404 error. Moreover, I cannot use 'archive-portfolio.php' method, it is limiting in some other aspects.

Comment: You'll have to create the query within the hooked function. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/how-to-force-a-404-on-wordpress/92176#92176) for setting a 404.